# How do I make an event entry repeat over consecutive days?

Tags: ms-access

I'm brand new to access and trying to 'learn on the fly'. I'm using 2003 version

I have a database to record staff sick leave tbls are tblLeaveEvent, tblEmployeeDetails, tblLeaveType.

I have a form to record the leave and all employee details are populated in the form by a query.
I select the leave start date from a calendar, leave type from a dropdown and leave duration from a list 0-5.

My problem is that if somebody calls in sick on Thursday and says they will be away for 3 work days my form records that as 3 days leave on Thursday.

How do I get the db to record 1-day leave for Thurs, 1-day leave for Fri and 1-day leave for Monday?

Do I need to change the design and select an end date rather than #days duration?
If I do select an end date from a Calendar how do I ignore w/ends?

Hopefully ther is a very simple solution to my problem.
Thnx,
David

Answer (score 0):

For nearly all databases that rely on dates, your own calendar table is a handy addition. It should contain a row for each date and some additional fields to indicate working days and such like. This will not only get rid of the weekend problem, but the public holiday problem as well. It is then easy to set 3 working days, it is just a matter of looking up the calendar table.

Calendar table

```
CalDate     Workday
04/09/2012      -1
05/09/2012      -1
06/09/2012      -1
07/09/2012       0
08/09/2012       0
09/09/2012      -1
10/09/2012      -1
```

[image: Add calendar days]

Roughly

```
Private Sub NoDays_AfterUpdate()
Dim rs As Recordset
Dim db As Database

    Set db = CurrentDb

    If Not IsNull(Me.Start) Then
        dteDate = DateAdd("d", Me.NoDays, Me.Start)
        sSQL = "SELECT TOP 1 c.CalDate FROM Calendar c " _
             & "WHERE c.CalDate >#" _
             & Format(dteDate, "yyyy/mm/dd") _
             & "# And c.WorkDay = True"
        Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(sSQL)

        If rs.EOF() Then
            MsgBox "Please perform calendar maintenance"
        Else
            Me.Return = rs!CalDate
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "Please enter start date"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Remou

Are you saying that I should add a new table called calendar? I don't understand how this solves my problem. Can you please elaborate.

Thank you.